# How to connect a streamlit app to multiple data sources

Tags: python, database, streamlit

I was going through https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/databases and wanted to use https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/connections/st.experimental_connection but I want the user to be given a choice on the data source he wants to connect to and then proceed.

Is there a way in streamlit to do this.

Comment: It depends on the credentials available to retrieve data, for instance, if you are making API Calls. You should expound on the actual challenge with this, to enable anyone assist you further.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `st.radio` ([API doc](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.radio)) to give the user a choice between multiple data sources. You'll just need to have conditional logic in your app that connects to the relevant data source based on the choice made by the user.